# thinking sphinx ordering by mixing capitals and lower case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-order-by, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have a rails application that is using thinking_sphinx for the searching. My problem is that the result returned is sorted with capitals first and lower case after it at the bottom. I'd like to mix them so that both 'A' and 'a' comes before 'B'. This is the method I'm using:

```
Company.search(query, :star => true, :page => params[:page], :per_page => 20, :order => :name, :sort_mode => :asc)
```

Comment: thinking_sphinx is on version 1.3.15, sphinx is 0.9.9-release (r2117) and rails 2.3.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maurício's answer is almost on the right track - but that's for transforming the text that Sphinx indexes for fields. When you're sorting, you're doing that by attributes (which don't use the charset table transformations).

What you'll need to do is separate the sorting attribute of name out from the field, and force the attribute version to use lowercase:

```
indexes :name
has "LOWER(companies.name)", :as => :name_sort
```

And then searching becomes:

```
Company.search query,
  :star      => true,
  :page      => params[:page],
  :per_page  => 20,
  :order     => :name_sort,
  :sort_mode => :asc
```

Comment: This worked, I had to add ':type => :string, :sortable => true' to make it work though. Cheers! (My full line is now: "has "LOWER(companies.name)", :as => :name, :type => :string, :sortable => true")

Comment: Ah, you're right, I forgot the `:type => :string` option - but you shouldn't need :sortable => true. Attributes are always sortable, so that option does nothing.

Comment: this worked for me too. I did indexing like  indexes "LOWER(listings.name)", :as=>:listing_name, :sortable => true.  thanks a ton.

Comment: How could I apply this to associations? I have a model Project that I search on which belongs_to a Company. I tried with indexes "LOWER(companies.name)" and indexes "LOWER(company.name)" without any results. (I have the type and sortable on there as well).

Comment: To answer my comment, you need a relation first so that the table joins on "companies". This can be done by indexes companies(:some_field) on a field that doesn't need the LOWER, alternatively the name field with another :as. Then you can use indexes "LOWER(companies.name)" in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure sphinx to transform the input, making uppercase letters become lowercase letters. You can do this with the ["charset_table" config](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-0.9.9.html#conf-charset-table).

And here's a [complementary tutorial](http://yob.id.au/2008/05/08/thinking-sphinx-and-unicode.html) on how to configure it with thinking_sphinx.

Comment: I tried to mess around with that but never got it to make any difference. What would an example config for this tag be to get this behavior I'm describing?

Comment: You can find a sample config for this field here -> http://yob.id.au/2008/05/08/thinking-sphinx-and-unicode.html

Comment: I tried this earlier as well, although it's still not changing anything. I looked at the development.sphinx.conf and it reads it in, but still no change to the ordering in the view.

Comment: That's insane. I don't have a thinking_sphinx based app at this moment here, but did you check the logs to see if thinking_sphinx itself is ordering the results with a SQL query instead of sphinx?

Answer (score 0):

After researching many hours I got simple and elegant solution for case insensitive search. Just define your index in following way.

```
indexes name, as: :name_sort, sortable: :insensitive
```