# Thinking Sphinx: Index combined columns and also use the LOWER function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713152/thinking-sphinx-ordering-by-mixing-capitals-and-lower-case) about using the "LOWER" function to help with sorting mixed case columns. I would like to do something similar but with a little more complex attribute. First, I have a basic many-to-many relationship:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_people
  has_many :people, :through => :project_people
end

class ProjectPerson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :person
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_people
  has_many :projects, :through => :project_people
end
```

I'm using TS to index projects:

```
class Project
  define_index
    indexes name, :sortable => true
    indexes [people.first_name, people.last_name], :as => :person, :sortable => true

    has created_at, category_id

    set_property :delta => true
  end
end
```

This indexes fine, but then I discovered the gotcha when upper and lower case letters are used in people's names. I tried replacing the call with following:

```
has ["LOWER(people.first_name)", "LOWER(people.middle_name)", "LOWER(people.last_name)"], :as => :person, :type => :string
```

But I kept getting error when rebuilding the index:

```
ERROR: index 'project_core': sql_range_query: Unknown column 'people.first_name' in 'field list' (DSN=mysql://...).
```

How can I implement the "LOWER(...)" function? Or, my actual question. How can I index this so I'll be able to sort projects by the person field and have it be case-insensitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example (normal column references, not SQL snippets), try setting `:sortable` to `:insensitive` instead of `true`.

Comment: Thanks man, great answer. I wonder why didn't I find this answer in documentation :(

Comment: Two reasons: the documentation isn't perfect (but patches are certainly welcome!), but also: this feature is not in TS v3 at this point in time (only in v1/v2). I'm not quite sure why it didn't make the cut (possibly not needed if Sphinx normalises string attributes itself), but again, testing and/or patches are welcome.